# Redirect all traffic

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am not an ASP developer so pretty lost here. Need to set up a rule to redirect *ANY* traffic coming to the server with .asp in the file name to another url. This is what I have in my web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
     <rules>
      <rule name="Migrate to PHP">
       <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+).asp" />
       <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/site/404" />
      </rule>
     </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works for /foo.asp, but does not work for /bar/foo.asp. How can I get a wildcard in there?

Comment: Have you configured IIS to let request to .asp files come through to the ASP.NET runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just remove the carat.

```
<match url="([_0-9a-z-]+).asp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `\.asp`, i.e. anything containing the explicit string `.asp`.

Comment: What about url parameters/query strings?

Comment: @Joel, yeah, didn't think about that.  Will drop the $.

Answer (score 0):

How about altering the pattern to ^(.*).asp$

```
<match url="^(.*)\.asp$" />
```